# How to execute pie chart once modal is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link on a page which I would like to open up and display a pie chart. However the Javascript executes immediately and therefore doesnt appear in the Modal form. Is there anyway to change this?

Link to modal:

```
 <a href="#graphModal" data-target="#graphModal" data-toggle="modal" class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" id="altChartButton" onclick="pieFunction()"></a>
```

Script:

```
<script id="pieCode">
        var width = 960,
           height = 500,
           radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

        var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(["#6ec393", "#9b80bb", "#e54a24"]);

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius - 10)
            .innerRadius(0);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(function (d) { return d.Value.Value; });

        var svg = d3.select("#pieData").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
          .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

        var data = @Html.Raw(@Model.output);

        var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
            .data(pie(data))
          .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc");

        g.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.data.Category.Category); });

        g.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-weight", "bold")
            .style("font-size", "15px")
            .style("font-family", "'futura-pt-n7', 'futura-pt', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif'")
            .text(function (d) { return d.data.Category.Category; });
    </script>
```

Modal:

```
 <div id="graphModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h1 style="text-align:center">Pie chart for: @Model.ReportDescription</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id="pieChart">
                       <div id="pieData"></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where's the definition of `pieFunction`?

Comment: @MaxArt var svg = d3.select("#pieData").append("svg"). That line calls the div in the modal. I thought it would execute

Comment: You seems to be a newbie in Javascript. Before understanding the problem you should learn how Javascript works, and jQuery. In particular, I see you're using Bootstrap, so take advantage of it and rely on the custom event it fires when the modal is opened. What you have to do is attaching a listener for the `show.bs.modal` event and draw your pie chart inside that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which libraries or frameworks you're using with this code but there is no pieFunction defined in any of the code you provided.

Without knowing more, the simplest solution might be to wrap the code inside your script tag in a function named pieFunction

```
function pieFunction(){
    //place code inside your script tag here...
}
```

However, if you want the code to execute after the modal is opened, you will likely need to execute the function in a callback instead. If you can post more details I may be able to help more. With bootstrap you would remove onclick="pieFunction()" and add the following on document ready:

```
$('#graphModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    pieFunction();
});
```

Comment: What details would you need as I do want it to execute after the modal is opened?

Comment: It looks like you might be using twitter bootstrap for your modal functionality http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals. If so, be sure to include the requisite css and js files from bootstrap. I've updated my answer to include how to execute the function after the modal has opened. If there are other frameworks you're using with the code be sure to post them.